# How is $\lim_{x\to 0}[(1+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}]^{10}=e^{10}$?

Tags: limits, eulers-number-e

**Problem:**

I was doing trying to find the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+5x)^{\frac{3x+2}{x}}$$

and I at some point reached these steps in my book:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+5x)^3.\lim_{x\to 0}[(1+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}]^{10}$$

$$(1+5\times0)^3.e^{10}$$

**Question:**

1. How does $\lim_{x\to 0}[(1+5x)^{\frac{1}{5x}}]^{10}=e^{10}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is based on the definition of $e$:
\begin{align*}
e = \exp(1) = \lim_{x\to 0}(1 + x)^{1/x}
\end{align*}

So you can obtain the desired result by means of the substitution $x = 5y$.

Comment: Is this true only when $\lim_{x\to 0}$?

Comment: Another equivalent definition is

$$e = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$$